# Tracing Che on OpenShift

Tags: openshift, trace, eclipse-che, jaeger

https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-7/tracing-che/ has a number of  environment variables to set to enable tracing.

Is it possible to set these when working on OpenShift? If so; where would the correct place be; and where will the Jaeger interface be available?

Thanks

Comment: The way how to setup environment variables on Che master may depend on the way how did you install  Eclipse Che. What was your way to install Eclipse Che?

Comment: OpenShift is the Saas Che offering - https://www.eclipse.org/che/getting-started/cloud/
So I didn't install it

Comment: che.openshift.io?

Comment: Yes - che.openshift.io

Comment: Since tracing is awailable only on che master, you as a user of che.openshift.io are not able to leverage on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to set these when working on OpenShift?

Yes, you can configure it for the Che master of your installation.

> OpenShift is the Saas Che offering

As a user of che.openshift.io you can't leverage from tracing capabilities of Che at this moment.